# splitting recently mixed sound file into two sounds in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, audiounit, audiotoolbox

I am mixing two different sounds which was recorded earlier and creating single sound file(.mp4) using AVMutableComposition and AVAudioMix..
first sound is of guitar, and second is of drum.

now i want split those two sounds from .mp4 file and have to create two different sound files.how to do this??

Please help..

Comment: what did you try doing?

Comment: hi león, actually its app requirement to mix 7 different sounds and to erase some of them later.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using amazing sound engine

http://theamazingaudioengine.com/

Recorded sound files differently and passed their channels together to audio player..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot decompose an .mp4 file. The only thing you can do is trim the sound clip to pieces.

Comment: thanks nikos. i want know if it is possible using linear PCM or using amplitude of both sounds

Comment: Using .mp4 it is impossible. Have you thought of using midi?

Comment: .mp4 is not compulsion. i can use any format..please tell me if its possible with any other format.